# How to create Facebook's app to add an overlay to profile picture?

Tags: node.js

Where do I start if I want to create Facebook app to add an overlay to my profile picture?

I have seen many changing their profile picture like support digital india or pray for french like profile pictures how do they do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now the only way that I know of is through this, https://www.facebook.com/fbcameraeffects/learn/

It's slowly rolling out so it might not be available for you until then. If someone else knows of a way through the API I'd love to know as well.